# LESS Syntax error?

Tags: css, joomla, less

I am in the process of recompiling the styling of a Joomla site I administer and was getting syntax errors. I looked at the line it complained about and didn't see anything wrong. So I dropped it in a [syntax checking utility](https://lesstester.com) and got the same error.

I haven't made any changes to this file, and I'm pretty sure its been years since anyone has touched it.

I don't do much front-end development and even less styling (pun slightly intended). Any ideas why this might be blowing up? Might a different version of LESS come out that's not compatible like it was?

Full syntax here: https://pastebin.com/6jU3BA2z

[image: Less syntax error that I don't understand]

```
.logoStyle (@index) when (@index > 0) { 
  (~".logo-type-preset@{index}")  {
        #rt-logo {
            background: url(../images/logo/preset@{index}/new_logo.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
            display: block;
            width: 600px;
            height: 65px;
            background-size: contain;   
            max-width: 100%;            
        }
    }
    .logoStyle (@index - 1);
}
.logoStyle (8);
```

Comment: `(~".logo-type-preset@{index}")` - this is old selector interpolation syntax abandoned in 2013. Modern syntax would be: `.logo-type-preset@{index}`.

Comment: @seven-phases-max very good to know. This is a very old template from 2013'ish timeframe so it makes sense it was using the old selector. I am going to purchase a newer version of the template which should have a newer LESS file